# WPF Binding nested objects

Tags: wpf, object, binding, nested

I'm very new to WPF and I'm having difficulties binding a ***request*** object with nested objects  which was derived from a WSDL to a XAML textbox. Programmatically I was able to bind to a textbox but I would like to understand the syntax needed to bind via XAML. Once I have some direction It'll make it much easier to research a full solution. Thanks

The ResultSet and Message Object will always be [0].

## Code

```
MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GetMarketingMessagesResponse request = new GetMarketingMessagesResponse();
    request = (GetMarketingMessagesResponse)XMLSerializerHelper.Load(request, @"C:\SSAResponse.xml");
    DataContext = request;
    Binding bind = new Binding();
    bind.Source = request.ResultSet[0].Message[0];
    bind.Path = new PropertyPath("SubjectName");
    this.txtbSubject.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
 }
```

The return value in the Visual Studio Watch ***bind.Source = request.ResultSet[0].Message[0];***
is
bind.Source = {GetMarketingMessagesResponseResultSetMessage} which is the class name.

## XAML

I'm looking for direction on how to bind to this class and the properties inside

```
<TextBox Name="txtbMessageDetails" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50.08,8,0"    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Source=ResultSet[0].Message[0], Path=SubjectName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87.96" Width="287.942"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a **[converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)** which will receive the request and extract the message.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MessageExtractorConverter x:Key="messageExtractorConverter" />
</Window.Resources>


<TextBox Name="txtbMessageDetails" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50.08,8,0"    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource messageExtractorConverter}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="87.96" Width="287.942"/>
```

Converter implementation:

```
public class MessageExtractorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = value as GetMarketingMessagesResponse;
        if (val != null)
        {
            // You can modify this code to extract whatever you want...
            return val.ResultSet[0].Message[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You already put the *request* object in your DataContext, making it the default *Source* for all bindings. So, instead of specifying another Source (which would just override the DataContext), you use the binding's Path to make your way from the DataContext to the property you need:

```
<TextBox Name="txtbMessageDetails" Text="{Binding Path=ResultSet[0].Message[0].SubjectName}" />
```

Here is an article explaining how the DataContext works, and how it is "inherited" from control to control in your Window: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF